# Appending text to network hosted file

Tags: c#, networking, text, append, unc

I have written a small utility and within it I want to be able to write to a network hosted log file to confirm which users have run the tool. I am easily able to create the file from within my utility but if I then try and append additional text I get met with:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.

I am able to create the file initially, if I delete it I can recreate it and if I run my code without the 'append' tag I can overwrite the file so I know that the access denied message is not a permissions thing.

Below is the code I'm using.

```
using (StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter(@"\\MyNetworkLocation\MyLogFile.csv",true))
{
   sw1.WriteLine(userName + "," + machineName + "," + 
         (string.Format("{0:dddd dd MMMM yyyy}", dt)));
}
```

Comment: Is it possible another process is writing to it at the same time, or has a lock on it otherwise?

Comment: You've got more than one person writing to the file.  This isn't supported.  You should just install Sql Express and write your logs to a network-available instance of that.

Comment: I don't think it is possible that anything else is using the file. At this point there is only me using the utility. If I manually edit the file ouside of my utility there is no problem with appending and saving. If I leave the file open and then run my utility I get met with a different message which makes sense:

Cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: UnauthorizedAccessException = The exception that is thrown when the operating system denies access because of an I/O error or a specific type of security error.

Comment: I changed the network share path to avoid publishing company data. The real path is 100% valid and obviosusly works as I am able to create the file using this line of code.

Comment: What happens if you develop the logging app and two people do something you want to log at the same time? Answer: UnauthorizedAccessException ... use a real database!

Comment: What account is the app running under? Network? Do they have 'modify' permissions on the newly created text file?

Comment: I'm guessing it is a security error but as the message is so vague, I don't know what that security issue is. The baffling thing is that this code allows me to create and overwrite the file with no problem - it is only append that throws this error.

Comment: Paul, this can still be done.. I suspect that if this application is run locally that it works which means that he has access to the FileShare.. what is probably happening here is that perhaps other users may not have access to the file share.. this is why it's probably better to write to a database.. Scrotty, do not assume that everyone has or shares the same permissions that you do

Comment: Is the file read-only?

Comment: Side note: scrotty, I've removed "new here/new to language/google alot" text from your post - there is generally no need for it. Also when adding sample code try to avoid horizontal scroll and keep sample small to avoid vertical scroll (this post have good small sample). Note that extra code (like strange mix of `+` and `string.Format` calls in this post) may distract from original question - minimal sample that still show the problem makes it less likely to happen.

Comment: `Scrotty` if it's the append that throws the error then you are misleading us what does the error state exactly when you are appending actually can you show the entire method where you are writing to the file I wonder if you have something Declared twice meaning the StreamWriter Object does step thru the code and use something like NotePad++ to view the file also try putting in some Flush() method as well you could call the Close Method as well if you look at using the FileMode properties I think that you will see that it's possible to do what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Firstly, I appreciate what people are saying about two people accessing the file etc. This utility is not meant as any kind of long-term thing. It is at this point my first attempt at porting a tool I wrote using LISP on AutoCAD onto C# for use on Revit. It runs once and once only but it is preferable that I can see a log file which records who has run the utility. The utility itself is not a logging app. Very basic and there are other ways of doing it but as I have explained, I am simply trying to port an existing utility and it works in all aspects other than the logging.

Comment: With regard to the 'misleading', I have written the error as displayed on screen so if it is misleading then I apologise but this is all I have to work with. There are no other bits of code that write any kind of text - just this one bit. Prior to that it looks at the version of a particular file, compares it to one on our server and if the two are different it copies the file off the server onto the workstation. Once the process is completed it writes to the text file and that is the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to write to a Database or EventLog for logging then change your code to the following and see if this would help

```
using (Stream fs= new FileStream(@"\\MyNetworkLocation\MyLogFile.csv", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read))
{
   fs.Write(userName + "," + machineName + "," + string.Format("{0:dddd dd MMMM yyyy}", dt));
   fs.Flush();
   fs.Close();
}
```

[FIle.Open Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725(v=vs.110).aspx)

> per MSDN

```
Parameters
path
Type: System.String
The file to open.
mode
Type: System.IO.FileMode
A FileMode value that specifies whether a file is created if one does not exist, and determines whether the contents of existing files are retained or overwritten.
access
Type: System.IO.FileAccess
A FileAccess value that specifies the operations that can be performed on the file.
share
Type: System.IO.FileShare
A FileShare value specifying the type of access other threads have to the file.
Return Value
Type: System.IO.FileStream
A FileStream on the specified path, having the specified mode with read, write, or read/write access and the specified sharing option.
```